# how can i access the value of "affiliate" using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

Buy
Seasons 1-2

```
    <where-to-watch-meta
      href="https://www.kmtrak.com/SM94M2/3HWS9F7/?uid=233&amp;cmp=rt_where_to_watch"
      affiliate="hulu"
      skeleton="panel"
      data-qa="affiliate-item">
      <where-to-watch-bubble
        image="hulu"
        slot="bubble"
        tabindex="-1"
      ></where-to-watch-bubble>
      <span slot="license">Subscription</span>
      <span slot="coverage">Seasons 1-2</span>
    </where-to-watch-meta>
```

onde_assistir = soup.find("where-to-watch-meta",property="image")["content"]

Comment: `soup.find("where-to-watch-meta").get("affiliate")`

Comment: thanks bro,but it only returns the first one,how can i access the other values                            <where-to-watch-meta
          affiliate="vudu"
          skeleton="panel"
          data-qa="affiliate-item">
          <where-to-watch-bubble
           image="vudu" 
          tabindex="-1"
          ></where-to-watch-bubble>
          <span slot="license">Buy</span>
          <span slot="coverage">Seasons 1-2</span>
        </where-to-watch-meta>
      
        <where-to-watch-meta
          affiliate="hulu" 
          skeleton="panel"
          data-qa="affiliate-item">

Comment: @CaioVeiga Have you tried to research yourself a bit? A cursory search would have led you to `find_all()`; does that not meet your requirements? If you have more than one element you’re trying to find, you should make that explicitly clear in your question.

Comment: Update your question with the new requirements.

Comment: Your sample code used `soup.find()`, which only finds one element, so I assumed you only wanted to find one.

Comment: @esqew my bad bro,first time using forum.

Answer (score 0):

Set "html" to the code that you provided, make soup, and use find_all.

```
all_values = soup.find_all(attrs={"affiliate": True})
```